# JBoss EAP 6.3 error :Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-eap-6

Whenever I am trying to start JBoss EAP 6.3 in eclipse, it gives me error as,

```
Cannot connect to VM 
com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException
```

and also,

```
Error:Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit
```

How to fix these errors?

Below are my configuration,

OS : Windows 7 32bit, Eclipse : Eclipse Luna 32 bit,

Answer (score 0):

I googled your error, and many people stated its an issue with avast anti virus.. If you have it installed, try turning it off and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Even I tried to search on google and got same answer. But Avast is not installed on machine.